# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException during onCreate of MainActivity.kt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, toolbar

I am unable to reproduce the error below myself, but in Google Play there are over 400 occurrences for this issue (I've tried on various Samsung and Pixel devices and still can't reproduce with SDK 30, 31, & 32):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4035)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4201)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2438)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8663)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:581)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar (AppCompatActivity.java:183)
  at org.fwac.fireweatheravalanche.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:319)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8290)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8270)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4009)
```

Here is the Kotlin code for MainActivity.kt **(line 319 is the setSupportActionBar() function)**:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

This is the layout file for MainActivity.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FireWeatherAvalancheCenter.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.FireWeatherAvalancheCenter.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've been searching all over the internet for a solution, but can't find one. Like I said, can't reproduce this issue so I'm left unable to make any changes. Would really appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your code and source code, the reason why it reports IllegalStateException is that it already has a actionBar.

```
final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
 if (ab instanceof WindowDecorActionBar) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("This Activity already has an action bar supplied " +
       "by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set " +
    "windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.");
  }
```

As for some devices reporting the error, it may the default theme is not same.
you can try to set the `windowActionBar` false in your theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: The theme I'm using is has the parent theme **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** and is calling `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` already

Comment: @TesmondH， you can check if set the `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` flag

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var photoFile: File

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Configurar el click listener del botón de captura
        captureButton.setOnClickListener {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent()
        }
    }

    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Manejar el error al crear el archivo de imagen
        }
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoFile)
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        ).apply {
            // Guardar la ruta del archivo para su uso posterior
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Mostrar la imagen capturada en la vista de imagen
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(photoFile))

            // Procesar y resolver la tarea a partir de la foto capturada
            resolverTarea(photoFile)
        }
    }

    // Función para procesar y resolver la tarea
    private fun resolverTarea(photoFile: File) {
        // Implementa el código necesario para resolver la tarea a partir de la foto capturada
        // Puedes utilizar bibliotecas como OpenCV o TensorFlow para el procesamiento de imágenes
        // y análisis según tus necesidades específicas.
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    }
}
```